# Issue with Deprecated Division warning in SASS

Tags: math, sass

I am doing a large project converting old SASS code (specifically node-sass), into the newer SASS using the SASS npm package, and I am getting this error message

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0. Recommendation: math.div(3, 4)
```

However, it seems to relate to this line of code

```
$_this: nth($short, $_i);
```

I am finding this confusing as I am not trying to divide the numbers, and the aren't separated by a `/`, can someone explain please, or at least help me with a solution, as ignoring the line isn't working either?

If it helps anyone, I have included the whole statement now...

```
@function parse-span(
  $short,
  $key: span
) {
  $_return: ();

  @if type-of($short) == map {
    $_return: $short;
  } @else {
    $_at: index($short, at);

    @if $_at {
      $_loci: $_at + 1;
      $_location: nth($short, $_loci);
      $_return: map-merge($_return, (location: $_location));
      $short: set-nth($short, $_at, null);
      $short: set-nth($short, $_loci, null);
    }

    $_i: 1;
    $_span: ();

    @while $_i <= length($short) {
      $_this: nth($short, $_i); <--- faulty line?

      @if type-of($_this) == number {
        $_span: append($_span, $_this);
        $short: set-nth($short, $_i, null);
      } @else if $_this == of {
        $short: set-nth($short, $_i, null);
        $_i: length($short) + 1;
      }

      $_i: $_i + 1;
    }

    @if length($_span) > 0 {
      $_span: if(length($_span) == 1, nth($_span, 1), $_span);
      $_return: map-merge($_return, ($key: $_span));
    }

    $_return: map-merge($_return, parse-grid($short));
  }

  @return $_return;
}

$_gutters: parse-span($short, gutter-override);
```

I have tried the solution in the comments but to no resolution.

Here is an image of the actual warning
[image: Deprecation Warning]

Comment: Not sure 100% without any additional code, but if you really think it's because of the nth. Try using dart sass built-in modules for that too. At the begging of the document add @use "sass:list"; and change it to $_this: list.nth($short, $_i);

Comment: I can't share anymore code because there isn't any I am afraid. However I will give your suggestion a go and see what happens ;)

Comment: I have updated this ticket as I really need some help now, this deprecation warning is just downright weird, and I could use a fresh pair of eyes on it :)

Comment: Why does the warning seem to relate to that line of code?

Comment: That's the one it highlights in the console, so I an assuming it is the one at fault. I have added an image to the original post

Comment: Where is the `{` that pairs with the last `}`?

Comment: Hi,
Sorry, that was a typo on my behalf

Comment: In `index($short, at)`, should `at` be undecorated?

Comment: Really not sure, it was like that when I got it, this was someone else's code, but they no longer work for us...